# Problem from a Calculus 2 course: Deducing $f(0)$ from $\int_{0}^{\pi}(f(x)+f''(x))\sin(x)~dx=-1$ and $f(\pi)=1$.

Tags: calculus

I have a little problem that somehow got me stumped. Given $\int_{0}^{\pi}(f(x)+f''(x))\sin(x)~dx=-1$, and $f(x)$ has a continuous 2nd derivative. Suppose that $f(\pi)=1$, compute $f(0)$. How do I do that? I took a derivative on both sides but plugging in $x=\pi$ then gave me $0=0$, so clearly I am not thinking in the right direction. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use integration by parts twice on:
$$\int_0^{\pi} f''(x)\sin(x)~dx$$

Comment: Ok, I got $\int_{0}^{\pi}(f''(x)sinxdx=f'(x)sinx -\int_{0}^{\pi}cosxf'(x)dx$, where the $f'(x)sinx$ becomes zero due to upper limit and lower limit being $\pi$ and $0$. Now what do I do?

Comment: You are on the right track. Integrate by parts one more time on $\int_0^{\pi} f'(x)\cos(x)~dx$.

Comment: I get $\int_{0}^{\pi}(f'(x)cosxdx=f'(x)cosx +\int_{0}^{\pi}sinxf(x)dx$, with a negative upfront. Plugging in upper and lower limit gives $2f(x) -\int_{0}^{\pi}(f(x)sinxdx$

Comment: So you have that:
$$\int_0^{\pi} f''(x)\sin(x)~dx=-[\cos(\pi)f(\pi)-\cos(0)f(0)]-\int_0^{\pi} f(x)\sin(x)~dx$$
How can you relate this, and the equation $\int_0^{\pi} (f(x)+f''(x))\sin(x)~dx=-1$?

Comment: Yes, I can try it from here. Thanks!

Comment: I will work it out later, my class is coming up. It's just algebra from here...

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts once $(\text{let }u=f)$ on 
$$
\int_0^{\pi} f(x)\sin(x)~dx
$$
Integrate by parts once $(\text{let }u=\sin x)$ on 
$$
\int_0^{\pi} f''(x)\sin(x)~dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

Given that:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \sin x dx +\int_{0}^{\pi} f''(x) \sin x dx=-1$$
Let us integrate the first integral by parts
$$=\left.-f(x)\cos x\right|_{0}^{\pi} +\int_{0}^{\pi} f'(x) \cos x dx+\int_{0}^{\pi} f''(x) \sin x dx=-1$$.
Let us integrate the second integral by parts to get
$$f(\pi)+f(0)+f'(x) \sin x|_{0}^{\pi}-\int_{0}^{\pi}f''(x) \sin x+\int_{0}^{\pi} f''(x) \sin x dx=-1$$
$$\implies f(\pi)+f(0)=-1 \implies f(0)=-2$$